# Flex mobile softkeyboard height and/or autocomplete suggestions

Tags: apache-flex, air

i'm trying to build an autocomplete textinput for an air mobile app. i want to determine whether to show a "List" above or below the textinput by calculating if the most available display area exists above or below it. obviously the soft keyboard will be on screen, so i'll need to know the height of it for this calculation.

i'm also open to suggestions for how to engineer an autocomplete textinput in general. most examples show a search bar located at the top of the app, but what do you do for a textinput contained within the "View" itself?

Answer (score 0):

For the [Flextras Mobile AutoCompleteComboBox](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&ProductID=21); we estimated the number of rows in the drop down assuming that the actual input was at the top of the view.  That number of rows, in turn, determines the height.  For our Nexus one; it was four elements.

In terms of implementation, the general concept is to use the PopUpManager to display the pop up.  When the user types text, filter the dataProvider somehow.

Our implementation uses a list w/ a vertical layout; but you could easily use a popup that shows a list with a horizontal layout.  The horizontal approach is similar to what is on the top of some mobile keyboards.

For a 'search bar' inside the app, as opposed to up top; I might change that search bar into a button.  Once the button is clicked, show a popup the same size of the screen that includes the text input at the top, with the drop down list of choices below it.

Does that help?

Comment: Actually, what I ended up doing was assume the keyboard started at 1/2 the height of the full stage. I don't think the component is fully completed, but you can check it out here: http://code.google.com/p/daleyjem/source/browse/trunk/com/daleyjem/flex/mobile/components/AutoComplete.mxml

Comment: The "half of stage" is probably a good assumption based on my casual usage of mobile devices w/ touch keyboards.  As a matter of policy; I don't dissect other Autocomplete implementations; but I do wish you the best of luck.